# SQL Developer creating extra triggers and sequences

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

For some tables, whenever I use Edit to edit the Oracle table, the Trigger and Sequence inputs show that a new trigger/sequence will be created. In this image, you can see that it will create #7...

[image]

If I change the drop-downs to a previously used trigger/sequence then click "OK", then re-open the edit window again, there is no change.

I'm using an Oracle Cloud database at the moment, but this database will be used in an 11.2 environment.

Comment: can you update your question to include the exact list of steps? what does your table start out as, what edits are you making, and how does the table end up at the end?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Not much more to add.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith How can I see in the SQL Developer which sequence is in use, without opening the Edit dialog?

Comment: Look at the trigger source code

Comment: That helped.  The newest trigger (#8) includes reference to a sequence, and all the old triggers have been changed to include `BEGIN NULL;` with no useful SQL statement, so it is no wonder that they can't be used.

Comment: what's not clear is how you got to this state...not sure how to advise/help you going forward without more info